# undefined method `model_name' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

The error: undefined method `model_name' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

I'm receiving this error when trying to render the haml below:

```haml
%section#banner
  .row
    .medium-12.columns
      %h2 Add Testimonial
      = simple_form_for(@testimonial) do |f|
        .row
          .large-6.columns
            = f.input :text, as: :text, 
            placeholder: 'Use this space to write a testimonial about the event(s) you participated.'
        .row
          .large-6.columns
            %p.description
            = sanitize('Any testimonial along with your name and profile picture might be used for the promotion of codebar (website, prospectus, etc).')
        .row
          .large-12.columns.text-right
            = f.submit 'Submit testimonial', class: 'button'
```

The controller is the following:

```ruby
class TestimonialsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :authenticate_member!

    def get_testimonial
        testimonial = Testimonial.where(member_id: testimonial_member_id)
        
        invitations = current_user.workshop_invitations.accepted_or_attended

        if invitations.any? and testimonial.blank?
            render 'new'
        else
            render 'show'
        end
    end

    def show
        @testimonial = Testimonial.find(testimonial_member_id)
    end

    def new
        @testimonial = Testimonial.new
    end

    def create
        @testimonial = Testimonial.new(testimonial_params)
        @testimonial.member_id = current_user
        @testimonial.public = false
        
        if @testimonial.save
            redirect_to @testimonial
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end


    private

    def testimonial_params 
        params.require(:testimonial).permit(:text)
    end

    def testimonial_member_id
        params[current_user]
    end
end
```

May someone help me see why is returning nil? If the variable is the same I'm passing on the new function?

Comment: **None of the code above mentions `model_name`**. What *exactly* does the error message say? It should include a *stack trace*, which shows exactly which line of code references `model_name`.

Comment: The way to debug this, though, is: Look at what variable `model_name` is being called on. Then look where that variable gets set. Then try to understand if something is going wrong in the variable-setting, or perhaps you just need to gracefully handle the scenario where it's `nil`.

Comment: However, I would also point out that your method: `TestimonialsController#testimonial_member_id` is super dodgy. Maybe that's supposed to be `params[:id]`???

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK `simple_form_for(@testimonial)` will try to call `@testimonial.model_name` so that's where the problem most likely originates.

If you go through the `get_testimonial` controller, you can end up at:

```
render 'new'
```

and that will render the HAML in question. But, notice that nothing in `get_testimonial` initializes `@testimonial` so `get_testimonial` will end up trying to `simple_form_for(nil)`.

Changing the bottom of `get_testimonial` to something more like this:

```
if invitations.any? && testimonial.blank?
  @testimonial = Testimonial.new
  render 'new'
else
  render 'show'
end
```

Your `show` template presumably needs a `@testimonial` as well so you might want to say `@testimonial = testimonial.first` before `render 'show'` too.

Also, I've changed your `and` operator to `&&` since you're generally better off pretending that `and` doesn't exist. The low precedence of `and` and `or` cause a lot of problems so you're better off sticking to `&&` and `||`.

I'm not sure of the logic for testimonials so you might be able to go with something more like:

```
def get_testimonial
  @testimonial = Testimonial.find_by(member_id: testimonial_member_id)
  invitations  = current_user.workshop_invitations.accepted_or_attended

  if invitations.any? && !@testimonial
    @testimonial = Testimonial.new
    render 'new'
  else  
    render 'show'
  end   
end
```

You might want to revisit your `testimonial_member_id` method as well, this:

```
def testimonial_member_id
  params[current_user]
end
```

looks odd, maybe it should be `params[:id]` instead.